# Setting up file sharing in Drupal 7

Tags: nodes, users, files

I would like to set up simple file storing and sharing (for educational purposes) for my users. I considered creating Profile2 profile and put data uploads files there. But it seems little clumsy.

Now i have idea to set up content types "File" Which will contain title and File upload field. That way they could possibly be able to "send" those nodes to anyonther somehow.

I could create listing of user files with views or else.

I am also using User Relationships module.

Question:
What would you suggest, what would be best method to achieve this ?
Is there mechanism for user to "send" node to another (User Relationships) ?
What is the danger of having extreme number of nodes that user can produce this way ?
Is there an alternative ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [Privatemsg](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module it had a nice attachment field and now it is fieldable that means you can add highly customizable file fields.

Thou Privatemsg module will work not as content type but more like internal messaging tool I also suggest checking out [Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) which depends on Messaging module. It will send emails upon creation or edit of chose content for all users you chose. You may also look into Team Notifications module which will allow your users to create subscriptions for others. Which is integrated with Organic groups module (OG). OG is best way for grouping and allowing users to group themselves yet if you are looking for a simple solution this may not fit due to it`s extensive functionality which results in fairly complex results.